# Counting back to events in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

How do you count the years since something happened in R? My data looks like this:

```
                 Year  Fatal  Non-Fatal
French Airline   1989    1       1 
French Airline   1990    1       0 
French Airline   1991    0       0
French Airline   1992    0       1
French Airline   1993    0       0
UK Airline       1989    1       1
UK Airline       1990    0       0
UK Airline       1991    1       0
UK Airline       1992    0       0
UK Airline       1993    0       0
```

Grouped by airline, I want to have an extra column that counts back to when the last fatal, or non-fatal crash happened. The output would then look something like this:

```
                 Year  Fatal  Non-Fatal  Since Fatal  Since Non-Fatal               
French Airline   1989    1       1           0              0
French Airline   1990    1       0           0              1
French Airline   1991    0       0           1              2
French Airline   1992    0       1           2              0 
French Airline   1993    0       0           3              1
UK Airline       1989    1       1           0              0 
UK Airline       1990    0       0           1              1
UK Airline       1991    1       0           0              2
UK Airline       1992    0       0           1              3
UK Airline       1993    0       0           2              4
```

In an ideal world I'd also have another column at the end that counts back to any kind of crash, fatal or non-fatal. How do I do it?

Comment: In the input and output the `Fatal', 'Non-Fatal' values are not the same.

Comment: My bad! Edited it now, of course it's meant to be the same.

Comment: Is it on purpose that you count a longer time without fatal several times as you increase Non-Fatal each time? E.g. French: 0,0,1,2,3: In some analysis this might look like data over 8 years - but it is 5 years.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. "Since Fatal" denotes the years since there was last a "1" value in "Fatal" for that particular airline. So if there wasn't a fatal crash for two years, there will be a "2" in "Since Fatal" and so forth. Does that clear it up?

Comment: @majom You shouldn't retag a question with packages based on the answers it gets; generally, it should just reflect what the OP had in mind when they asked.

Comment: Just following http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37672/when-should-you-edit-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using joins and requiring version 1.9.7+ of the package:

```
library(data.table)

# data borrowed from @majom's answer

d[, sf := 
  d[as.logical(Fatal)][d, on=.(Airline, Year), roll=TRUE, Year-x.Year]]

d[, sn := 
  d[as.logical(Non_Fatal)][d, on=.(Airline, Year), roll=TRUE, Year-x.Year]]

d[, sa := 
  d[as.logical(pmax(Fatal, Non_Fatal))][d, on=.(Airline, Year), roll=TRUE, Year-x.Year]]
```

which gives

```
           Airline Year Fatal Non_Fatal sf sn sa
 1: French_Airline 1989     1         1  0  0  0
 2: French_Airline 1990     1         0  0  1  0
 3: French_Airline 1991     0         0  1  2  1
 4: French_Airline 1992     0         1  2  0  0
 5: French_Airline 1993     0         0  3  1  1
 6:     UK_Airline 1989     1         1  0  0  0
 7:     UK_Airline 1990     0         0  1  1  1
 8:     UK_Airline 1991     1         0  0  2  0
 9:     UK_Airline 1992     0         0  1  3  1
10:     UK_Airline 1993     0         0  2  4  2
```

Alternately, for the last one: `d[, sa := pmin(sf, sn)]` if you've already computed those.

The coercion to logical should be a hint that those cols ought to be stored as logical already...

Comment: Thank you! I'm a newbie. What do you mean by the package? R?

Comment: Oh, I meant the data.table package that you tagged in your question. If you're not familiar with it, I'd suggest starting here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started Version 1.9.7 is the current development version, with installation instructions here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation Oh, d'oh. Just noticed that majom was the one to add that tag to your question.

Comment: @Akrun Two things are: `x.Year` is the big one, now available to refer to `x` cols in `x[i]` merges. The minor one is using `on=.(x,y)` instead of `on=c("x","y")`. I think this `roll` was one of the very early features.

Comment: @Frank thank you. I'm going through the installer and am stuck here: "Following that add these two lines to the file ~/.R/Makevars using your favourite text editor. It's likely you need to create the .R directory and the file Makevars in it if it doesn't already exist." It makes it sounds like the file already exists? I can't find it. I'm using Mac.

Comment: @vio (I don't use OSX, but I think they mean:) You can make the folder through the file browser. Then open TextEdit, which comes with every Mac, make a blank file, put just those two lines in it and save it as "Makevars" (without any file extension) in that folder.

Comment: @Frank OSX is strange. I did that and loaded the package normally and I get this data.table 1.9.6  For help type ?data.table or https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki
The fastest way to learn (by data.table authors): https://www.datacamp.com/courses/data-analysis-the-data-table-way

Attaching package: 'data.table'

The following object is masked _by_ '.GlobalEnv':

    .N 

-----

So obviously I did it wrong. I'll try the other way. Thank you very much in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is way to calculate the variables through the help of the cumuluated sums of fatal/non-fatal/any crashes by airline:

```
# Load required package
library(data.table)

# Setup data
d <- fread("Airline Year  Fatal  Non_Fatal
French_Airline   1989    1       1 
French_Airline   1990    1       0 
French_Airline   1991    0       0
French_Airline   1992    0       1
French_Airline   1993    0       0
UK_Airline       1989    1       1
UK_Airline       1990    0       0
UK_Airline       1991    1       0
UK_Airline       1992    0       0
UK_Airline       1993    0       0", header=T)

# Since fatal calculation
d[ ,Cumsum.Fatal:=cumsum(Fatal), by=Airline]
d[Fatal!=1, Since.Fatal:=1:.N, by=list(Airline, Cumsum.Fatal)]
d[Fatal==1, Since.Fatal:=0]

# Since non-fatal calculation
d[ ,Cumsum.Non_Fatal:=cumsum(Non_Fatal), by=Airline]
d[Non_Fatal!=1, Since.Non_Fatal:=1:.N, by=list(Airline, Cumsum.Non_Fatal)]
d[Non_Fatal==1, Since.Non_Fatal:=0]

# Since any (fatal or non-fatal) crash 
d[, Any_Crash:=ifelse(I(Fatal+Non_Fatal)>=1, 1, 0)]
d[ ,Cumsum.Any_Crash:=cumsum(Any_Crash), by=Airline]
d[Any_Crash!=1, Since.Any_Crash:=1:.N, by=list(Airline, Cumsum.Any_Crash)]
d[Any_Crash==1, Since.Any_Crash:=0]
```

The final `data.table` looks like that:

```
# > d
# Airline           Year Fatal Non_Fatal Cumsum.Fatal Since.Fatal Cumsum.Non_Fatal Since.Non_Fatal Any_Crash Cumsum.Any_Crash Since.Any_Crash
# 1: French_Airline 1989     1         1            1           0                1               0         1                1               0
# 2: French_Airline 1990     1         0            2           0                1               1         1                2               0
# 3: French_Airline 1991     0         0            2           1                1               2         0                2               1
# 4: French_Airline 1992     0         1            2           2                2               0         1                3               0
# 5: French_Airline 1993     0         0            2           3                2               1         0                3               1
# 6:     UK_Airline 1989     1         1            1           0                1               0         1                1               0
# 7:     UK_Airline 1990     0         0            1           1                1               1         0                1               1
# 8:     UK_Airline 1991     1         0            2           0                1               2         1                2               0
# 9:     UK_Airline 1992     0         0            2           1                1               3         0                2               1
# 10:    UK_Airline 1993     0         0            2           2                1               4         0                2               2
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is more efficient way on how to write the command courtesy of [Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191259/frank) (see comments):

```
d[, sf := seq(.N)-1L, by=.(Airline, cumsum(Fatal))][, snf := seq(.N)-1L, by=.(Airline, cumsum(Non_Fatal))][, sa := seq(.N)-1L, by=.(Airline, cumsum(pmax(Fatal, Non_Fatal)))][]

# Airline           Year Fatal Non_Fatal Cumsum.Fatal Since.Fatal Cumsum.Non_Fatal Since.Non_Fatal Any_Crash Cumsum.Any_Crash Since.Any_Crash sf snf sa
# 1: French_Airline 1989     1         1            1           0                1               0         1                1               0  0   0  0
# 2: French_Airline 1990     1         0            2           0                1               1         1                2               0  0   1  0
# 3: French_Airline 1991     0         0            2           1                1               2         0                2               1  1   2  1
# 4: French_Airline 1992     0         1            2           2                2               0         1                3               0  2   0  0
# 5: French_Airline 1993     0         0            2           3                2               1         0                3               1  3   1  1
# 6:     UK_Airline 1989     1         1            1           0                1               0         1                1               0  0   0  0
# 7:     UK_Airline 1990     0         0            1           1                1               1         0                1               1  1   1  1
# 8:     UK_Airline 1991     1         0            2           0                1               2         1                2               0  0   2  0
# 9:     UK_Airline 1992     0         0            2           1                1               3         0                2               1  1   3  1
# 10:    UK_Airline 1993     0         0            2           2                1               4         0                2               2  2   4  2
```

Comment: Right. Updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you need to save the cumsum or ifelse in a column, nor treat cases separately with == and != 1. For example, `d[, sf := seq(.N)-1L, by=.(Airline, cumsum(Fatal))][, snf := seq(.N)-1L, by=.(Airline, cumsum(Non_Fatal))][, sa := seq(.N)-1L, by=.(Airline, cumsum(pmax(Fatal, Non_Fatal)))][]` seems to do it...?

Comment: True. Thanks. I did not think much about optimizing in the first place, but rather wanted to illustrate the steps how one might think about the problem. Chaining is always elegant, but often unreadable for newbies. Do you want to add your approach as a separate answer or should I add it to my answer and give you credits?

Comment: Yeah, i didn't mean necessarily chaining (that just made it more compact to fit into a comment), just the skipping creation of new columns and using pmax in place of ifelse and `I()` (not sure what `I()` is doing here...). Anyway, yeah, I commented so you could add it if you want. Fine without attribution because it's a simple extension, but either way.

Comment: @Frank I just can't seem to get lucky on this. If I do the updated way, it counts back to the year where an Airline first appears, not the last crash event. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @majom I just can't seem to get lucky on this. If I do the updated way, it counts back to the year where an Airline first appears, not the last crash event. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have some data where the provided scripts fail?